# How to click on image which then go to another page and auto-check specific checkbox

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have page 1 which has 3 images. On the next page, there are 3 check boxes with the same id as the images. Roughly like this:

**Page 1**

```
[image1] [image2] [image3]
```

**Page 2**

```
[ ] Checkbox for image1
[ ] Checkbox for image2
[ ] Checkbox for image3
```

When I click on `[image1]`, I was hoping to auto-check the checkbox for image1 on page 2. How do I do this?

I tried to apply these codes but it didn't work. Where do I get it wrong? Any helpful suggestion is highly appreciated.

**php for Page 1:**

```
<a href="page2.php?id=image1">image1</a>
<a href="page2.php?id=image2">image2</a>
<a href="page2.php?id=image3">image3</a>
```

**Page2:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image1" <?php if($id == 'image1'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 1" /> Image 1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image2" <?php if($id == 'image2'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 2" /> Image 2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image3" <?php if($id == 'image3'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 3" /> Image 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this PHP code to Page 2

```
<?php $id=$_GET['id']; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image1" <?php if($id == 'image1'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 1" /> Image 1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image2" <?php if($id == 'image2'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 2" /> Image 2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image3" <?php if($id == 'image3'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 3" /> Image 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

When you add `?variable=value` to the end of a URL, that variable is located in the $_GET array for the page that loads. Thus you're check box would have this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image1" <?php if($_GET['id'] == 'image1'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 1" /> Image 1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image2" <?php if($_GET['id'] == 'image2'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 2" /> Image 2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image3" <?php if($_GET['id'] == 'image3'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 3" /> Image 3
```

To be safe, many times it's good to check that the variable exists before trying to access it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image1" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'] && $_GET['id'] == 'image1'){echo "checked";} ?> value="Image 1" /> Image 1
```